# Absolutely no light showing...totally at a loss

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Really can't understand why I can't see anything.  Tried moving lamp and camera, increasing strength, but nothing.  Can't even see light in the lamp preview.  I'm pretty new to Blender, so I feel like I must've done something accidently along the way.

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38975

Comment: It renders for me and the [result can be seen](http://imgur.com/nPHVhfq). Probably it's not as expected because your [lamp is almost inside](http://imgur.com/ud13JQ5) of one of the cubes, but still you should see something in scene.

Comment: Same here, works fine. Something else is off. Maybe graphics drivers? Can you render anything at all? New default scene with cube and single point lamp? Anything in cycles?

Comment: Turns out it was a background issue!  Didn't realize that heavily affected lighting.  I don't even use lighting anymore for this project.

Answer (score 1):

It seems fine for me, I get quite a neat render. [image]
But if you want it to light up all of the boxes, just change it to a sun lamp. 
[image]
If this is not what you were asking for, or I am not clear, please tell me.
Thanks!

Comment: Hey no you guys were totally right.  It was a lighting issue, but also I found out it was a background issue!  I guess being a noob, I didn't realize that having a black background would actually affect the lighting on the object itself.  I thought it was neutral.